# Need to stop my terrible edit

Tags: support, edits, specific-edit

I misunderstood an answer that I think wasn't written very well, but I made a [bad edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14887296). The answer is here: [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation/1364491#1364491).

EDIT: I actually don't have justification, I was just wrong. Bad thinking for a couple minutes there.

Anyway, can I have that edit rejected? Now knowing what the author was trying to say, an edit isn't appropriate for what I would change.

Comment: If such completely wrong change is approved it may be worth flagging post for moderator attention with "other" flag on the post like "other: I made really wrong edit and could not find a way to stop it before it got approved - please check if *reviewers acted correctly* (and let me know if I should revert the edit myself".

Comment: Before your edit is approved, you can always modify it, so you should be able to revert the edit in the queue before anyone even looks at it. That way, you can fix your mistake and either push a "null" edit (which is very likely to be rejected, and if approved doesn't hurt anything), or you can actually make a couple of reasonable, albeit minor, fixes.

Comment: weird that you would even think that a highly voted 7 year old answer was wrong in the first place

Comment: @charlietfl: Why? It happens.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The edit has been rejected. So nothing to worry about now.

I think it would have been naturally rejected anyway because:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Also for the next time, no need to make a meta post. If you fear your edit might be wrongly approved, just join a moderation chat room (e.g. [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)) and leave a message there that you want your edit rejected.

Comment: "join a moderation chat room and leave a message there that you want your edit rejected" [Example](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=31963725#31963725)

Comment: Also waiting 5-10 minutes for change to go through review and making "rollback" edit if needed may be faster.